# Highlighting array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of statistics on racing dogs. I need to highlight the maximum and minimum values in each element by adding another element. Let me explain.

**Example of array**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 31.06
            [av_calc_7] => 25.03
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 16.74
            [av_calc_7] => 18.06
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 30.93
            [av_calc_7] => 31.06
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 29.01
            [av_calc_7] => 25.08
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 30.72
            [av_calc_7] => 31.02
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 31.16
            [av_calc_7] => 36.02
        )

)
```

**Example of resulting array**

I need to compare these values and add another element specifying if it is the highest of lowest value. For example, it should generate an array such as the following.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 31.06
            [av_calc_7] => 25.03
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 16.74
            [fast_calc_7_lowest] => TRUE
            [av_calc_7] => 18.06
            [av_calc_7_lowest] => TRUE
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 30.93
            [av_calc_7] => 37.06
            [av_calc_7_highest] => TRUE
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 29.01
            [av_calc_7] => 25.08
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 30.72
            [av_calc_7] => 31.02
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [fast_calc_7] => 31.16
            [fast_calc_7_highest] => TRUE
            [av_calc_7] => 36.02
        )

)
```

I'm sure there is a really simple way to do this. The more I have to iterate through arrays, the slower my application gets!

Thanks guys.

**EDIT: How data is sourced**

1. JSON array gathered from greyhound website for each dogs "race history"
2. JSON array is processed to form a nice array for each dogs history with the data for example the time for each race, finishing position etc.
3. This data is then calculated for each dog to find the fastest time, average time and other data. This is the array above. (Each array is a different dog).
4. At this point, I need the array processed to add in the highlighting elements.

Comment: Where do you get your arrays from? Usually, this kind of thing is best handled at the source (i.e, when loading from database, file, whatever...).

Comment: I have edited my answer to add in information on how the data is sourced. I can't see any way of comparing the dogs against each other before this point as all the data is collected separately before being merged together into one array and subject to the calculations.

Comment: Ack, different JSON-sources don't lend themselves very easily to aggregate  data. Looping through the data seems to be the only solution, although you could (1) already keep track of min/max values when determining faster & avg. race, saving you one loop (2) if you really want to limit your loops, keep track of a `reference` to the min/max dogs if the array, which would mean no other loop is necessary, but the added debug-pitfalls and the fact that a lot of PHP-devs don't properly understand references might weigh in to just decide to have an extra loop just for clarity & ease of debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much to it. You need to loop over the array, maintaining variables with the indexes of the high/low elements so far for each attribute. After the loop, access those elements and add your extra data.

```
$lowAverage = $highAverage = array('index' => null, 'value' => 0);
$lowFast = $highFast = array('index' => null, 'value' => 0);
foreach($dogs as $index => $data) {
    if($lowAverage['index'] == null || $data['av_calc_7'] < $lowAverage['value']) {
        $lowAverage = array('index' => $index, 'value' => $data['av_calc_7']);
    }
    if($highAverage['index'] == null || $data['av_calc_7'] > $highAverage['value']) {
        $highAverage = array('index' => $index, 'value' => $data['av_calc_7']);
    }

    // same for $lowFast, $highFast
}

if($lowAverage['index'] != null) {
    $dogs[$lowAverage['index']]['av_calc_7_lowest'] = true;
}

// same for the other 3 values
```

Comment: Worked like a dream. This definitely seems to me like the most elegant, although somewhat repetitive method of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: @Dan: you can cut down on the repetition some by refactoring some of it to (possibly anonymous) functions and/or cleverish `array_reduce` use. The important thing is that the code looks clean and understandable to the person who maintains it.